# Make HTML5 sandbox work for IE8/9 using polyfill or shim

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, sandbox, polyfills

I would like to make the new HTML5 Iframe attribute `sandbox` work in IE8 and 9. I have Googled for about a day now and tried many "libraries" which are supposed to make HTML5 work, but they don't seem to have "sandbox" included.

So my question; Where can I find a polyfill/shim/plugin/snippet or anything else to make the Iframe `sandbox` work in IE8/9 ?

Comment: Can you list plugins and anything else you have tried so people do not suggest those?

Comment: @David Starkey https://code.google.com/p/html5shiv/  https://github.com/aFarkas/html5shiv/

Comment: Oh I just realized its the same script, it doesn't matter though. I tried many things which didn't work. So the question is not point to a link but "be absolutly sure" that it will work and then tell me about it:)

Comment: `sandbox` is something which needs to be implemented in the browser, if it was possible to implement the same functionality in a JavaScript shim there would be no need to invent the attribute in the first place.

Comment: @robertc But aret all the other shims Javascript generated..? But I see your point, thanks.

Comment: @robertc Do you think this will work http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/windowsapps/JavaScript-iframe-sandbox-0f077ece

Comment: I think it'll work on IE10 as per the operating system requirements on the page

Comment: @robertc Thank you for noticing that :) (to bad..)

Answer (score 4):

As others have noted you cannot get this to work in JavaScript alone, I would say your best bet is to use the security="restricted" IE only attribute.

See here : http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ie/archive/2008/01/18/using-frames-more-securely.aspx

Comment: what versions of ie support  security="restricted"

Comment: aWebDeveloper: per the article linked to, IE6+ support `security="restricted"`.